# $\sum_{k=0}^\infty|f(x+k)|\in L^\infty(I)$ for all bounded interval $I$.

Tags: real-analysis

Recently, I get stuck on this problem which appear on a previous real analysis qualifying exams.

Let $f,f^\prime\in L^1(\Bbb R)$, $g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty|f(x+k)|$ then $g\in L^\infty(I)$ for all bounded interval $I$.

In fact, I am wondering what's the meaning of $f^\prime\in L^1$, whether it is $f^\prime$ exists a.e. $\Bbb R$ and $f^\prime\in L^1$ or $f$ is in the Sobolev space $W^{1,1}$. The difference between the two cases is that $f$ may not be AC in the first case and it is in the second case. But a sad thing is that I cannot prove the result under either of the assumptions. It easily seen that $g\in L^1[0,1]$ so that the sum converges a.e. on $[0,1]$ and hence on $\Bbb R$. But I just don't know how to use the condition $f^\prime\in L^1$ to get the conclusion. Any hint or suggestion on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $f\in W^{1,1}(\mathbb R)$, we will show that, for almost every $a\in\mathbb R$, $g\in L^{\infty}(a,a+1)$.

Indeed, using that $g\in L^1(J)$ for all intervals $J$ of length $1$, then for almost every $a\in\mathbb R$, $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|f(a+k)|<\infty.$$ Let now $h\in L^1(a,a+1)$ and set $h_0(x)=\int_a^x|h|$. Then, integrating by parts, $$\begin{align*}\int_a^{a+1}|gh|&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_a^{a+1}|f(x+k)||h(x)|\,dx=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_a^{a+1}|f(x+k)|h_0'(x)\,dx\\ &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(|f(a+1+k)|h_0(a+1)-\int_a^{a+1}|f(x+k)|'h_0(x)\,dx\right)\\ &\leq\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(|f(a+1+k)|+\int_a^{a+1}|f'(x+k)|\,dx\right)\|h\|_{L^1(a,a+1)}\\ &\leq\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|f(a+1+k)|+\|f'\|_{L^1(\mathbb R)}\right)\|h\|_{L^1(a,a+1)}.\end{align*}$$ By duality, this implies that $g\in L^{\infty}(a,a+1)$.

Comment: Nice proof. Thank you.